# Are Google Play and Apple Store allows InAppBrowser of ionic to view a website only?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, google-play, apk

Before create a new account for iOS, android to upload web app to Google play and apple store, I want to ask:

Are they allows developer to upload an application that use InAppBrowser of Ionic to view website through that uploaded app ?

We need this to keep our work up to the latest date of updates for all users without need so many versions for both iOS and android.

So, are there any positive, negative or past experiences related to this topic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the review guidelines from Apple, https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ it states that

> 4.2 Minimum Functionality
>
> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store.

I would make the case to package your app as an Ionic app, and use either Ionic Deploy, or Code Push to update the content of your app on the fly. Note: This type of deployment cannot update Cordova dependencies, but it does let you keep your html, css and js files up to date.

Answer (score 1):

In general yes, they allow this, but they might get confused (specially Apple) and ask you to be careful about the links that you open inside your app.

For example, Apple has certain guidelines about apps that buy/sell cryptocurrency. If you put a link to a buy/sell cryptocurrency website and open it inside the inAppBrowser, the app reviewer might "think" your app is for buying/selling cryptocurrencty and you might get rejected as a result.

However, if you put links to normal website, for example CNN, they should be ok with it, as there are many apps that already do this.